Internal conditions for product and disjoint union of topological spaces
I was studying general topology when a question came to my mind.
Given some topological spaces, say two, there are notable ways to equip their union and their Cartesian product with a topology, i.e. disjoint union topology and product topology. In both cases, the given spaces are (possibly non-canonically) homeomorphic to some subspaces of the constructed spaces.
Inspired by similar circumstances in group theory, e.g. defining external product of groups and then identifying conditions under which a given group is isomorphic to the internal product of two of its subgroups (of course, the reverse approach can equally be pursued), I wonder if something similar exists in topology.
Are there any notable conditions under which a topological space is homeomorphic to (or coincides with) the product or the disjoint union of two of its subspaces?

Define "notable." Also, you should posit that the subspaces are nonempty for coproduct and not singletons for the product. For the disjoint union, this is the case iff $X$ can be decomposed into (nonempty) disjoint clopens $A$ and $B$, so this applies whenever $X$ is disconnected and has open components, for instance, say, if $X$ is disconnected & locally connected, in particular disconnected & discrete.

Open components can give you a decomposition as disjoint union of connected components, but to decompose any space you just need a partition into open sets $U_i$, in which case $X = \bigsqcup_{i\in I} U_i$. For products I think it would be more natural to consider based spaces $X$ with some base point $x\in X$ and then given two subspaces $A, B$ with $A\cap B = {x}$ to ask for conditions such that there is a homeomorphism $X \cong A\times B$ which sends $A$ to $A\times {x}$ and $B$ to ${x}\times B$.

@BenSteffan As far as I know, topological spaces (and thus subspaces) are non-empty by default, but of course otherwise the condition is necessary. By "notable" I mean just different from a direct rephrasing of the definition of homeomorphism applied to the above cases.

Maybe whatever material you're working with assumes that, but this is very much not a general assumption. In any case my remark about singletons is unaffected by this.

@BenSteffan Thank you for the info.

Not a very interesting condition, but if $X$ is a locally connected space with homeomorphic components, $A$ is one of the components and $B$ is chosen by picking one element from each of the components, then $X\cong A\times B$.
